# Prove $\overline{f(D_r(a))}\subset D_r(a)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$. $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(\Omega)\subset \Omega$ and $\exists a:f(a)\neq a$. Then exists $r$ such that

(1) If $|f'(a)|<1$ is $\overline{f(D_r(a))}\subset D_r(a)$

(2) If $|f'(a)|>1$ is $D_r(a)\subset  \overline{f(D_r(a))}$

I don't know how to use the condition $|f'(a)|<1$ and $|f'(a)|>1$. Is it right if I say that we can consider for $z=x+iy$ the function as $f=u(x,y) + iv(x,y) $ and then $|f'(a)|=u_{x}(a)v_y(a)-u_y(a)v_x(a)<1$ ? But I don't think is helpful.

Comment: Not true. It is true if you say that $f$ is not the identity map, but $f(a)=a$, for some $a\in\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true.

Consider $f(z)=-z/2$, and $\Omega$ the unit disk, and $a=1/2$.  Then $D_r(a)\subset \Omega$, provided that $r\le 1/2$. Also $f'(z)=-1/2$, and hence $|\,f'(a)|<1$. Meanwhile 
$$
f\big(D_r(1/2)\big)=D_{r/2}(-1/4)
$$ 
and hence
$$
\overline{f\big(D_r(1/2)\big)}\not\subset D_r(1/2)
$$
since $-1/4\not\in D_r(1/2)$.